# With Parsec, how do I parse zero or more foo1 terminated by foo2 and all separated by dot?

Tags: haskell, parsec

What I am trying to do seems pretty simple, but since I am a parsec Haskell newb, the solution is eluding me.

I have two parsers, let's say `foo1` and `foo2` where `foo1` can parse a intermedate term and `foo2` parses an ending term. Terms are separated by a symbol, `"."`.

Sentences that I need to parse are

- `foo2`
- `foo1.foo2`
- `foo1.foo1.foo2`

and so on.

My original thought was to do

```
do k <- sepBy foo1 (char'.')
   j <- foo2
```

but that wouldn't catch the `foo2`-only case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `endBy`, not `sepBy`.

```
foo = do k <- foo1 `endBy` char '.'
         j <- foo2
         ...
```

That will force the separator to be present after each occurrence of `foo1`.

Of course, `endBy` is trivially replaceable by `many`, which may be clearer.

```
foo = do k <- many $ foo1 <* char '.' 
         j <- foo2
         ...
```

or, without `Control.Applicative`:

```
foo = do k <- many $ do x <- foo1; char '.'; return x
         j <- foo2
         ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you want `endBy` instead of `sepBy`:

```
do k <- endBy foo1 (char'.')
   j <- foo2
```

Second, it would

> catch the just foo2 case

From the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:endBy):

> `endBy p sep` parses **zero or more** occurrences of `p`, separated by `sep`. Returns a list of values returned by `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
many (foo1 >>= (\v -> char '.' >> return v)) >>= \v1 ->
  foo2 >>= \v2 ->
  -- ...
  -- combine v1 & v2 somehow
```

(Just a sketch, of course.)

In general, the `many` combinator is Parsec's equivalent of [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star); and if you're going to add something simple like a trailing dot to an existing parser, using `>>` / `>>=` may actually be cleaner and simpler than using `do` notation.

Answer (score 0):

sure, it would catch the foo2 case.   Using for your foo1, Leiden's word:

```
let a = sepBy word (char '.')
parseTest a "foo.bar.baz"
parseTest a "foo"
parseTest a ".baz"
```